Server sent events - request limits handling
I have to use an external API. On request, it streams the events or data every second.

According to their API document, they accept only 2 requests in a minute. But we would have 100s of users in a minute.
How to make the live data accessible to all the users with just 2 requests in a minute?

I was thinking of reading the stream for about 30seconds and store in redis cache and make the request again but I don't think it's a good approach.
